# Giving examples to counter a false statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification

Provide a counter-example to demonstrate that the following statement is false.

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R} (\sqrt{x^2y^2} \geq 16) \rightarrow (xy \geq 4)$

My attempt:

Statement $P$: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R} (\sqrt{x^2y^2} \geq 16) \rightarrow (xy \geq 4)$

For $x = 16$ and $y = -1$:
$\sqrt{x^2y^2} = \sqrt{16^2 \times (-1)^2} = \sqrt{16^2 \times 1} = 16 \geq 16$
$xy = 16 \times (-1) = -16 < 4$

Therefore, $P$ is false for $x=16$ and $y=-1$:
$P$ is not true for all values of $x$ and $y$ in the set of real numbers.

This counter-example shows that the implication in statement $P$ does not hold for all possible values of $x$ and $y$.

Therefore, the statement $P$ is false.

Am I correct ?

---

**Correction to implement the suggestion from the Answer below:**

My attempt:

Statement $P$: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R} (\sqrt{x^2y^2} \geq 16) \rightarrow (xy \geq 4)$

This counter-example shows that the implication in statement $P$ does not hold for all possible values of $x$ and $y$.

For $x = 16$ and $y = -1$:
$\sqrt{x^2y^2} = \sqrt{16^2 \times (-1)^2} = \sqrt{16^2 \times 1} = 16 \geq 16$
$xy = 16 \times (-1) = -16 < 4$

It is false that every real pair of $x$ and $y$ satisfies $(\sqrt{x^2y^2} \geq 16) \rightarrow (xy \geq 4)$

- i.e., $\Big(∀x{\in}\mathbb R\;∀y{\in}\mathbb R \;S(x,y)\Big)$ is false.

Therefore, the statement $P$ is false.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Statement $P$: $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R} (\sqrt{x^2y^2} \geq 16) \rightarrow (xy \geq 4)$$

> This counter-example shows that **the implication in statement $P$ does not hold for all possible values of $x$ and $y$.**

You’ve given an appropriate counterexample. However, your above sentence makes a logical leap by wrongly claiming that

- $(\sqrt{x^2y^2} \geq 16) \rightarrow (xy \geq 4)$ is false for every real pair of $x$ and $y\quad\quad\color{red}{\text{including }(x,y)=(5,5)}$
- i.e., $∀x{\in}\mathbb R\;∀y{\in}\mathbb R\; \Big(S(x,y) \text{ is false}\Big).$

Correction:

- It is false that every real pair of $x$ and $y$ satisfies $(\sqrt{x^2y^2} \geq 16) \rightarrow (xy \geq 4)$
- i.e., $\Big(∀x{\in}\mathbb R\;∀y{\in}\mathbb R \;S(x,y)\Big)$ is false.